# How do you get z/OS USS to use the up-arrow and down-arrow keys to scroll command history?

Tags: ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history

When connecting to z/OS (USS) using, I'd like the USS shell to handle keys the same way they do in Ubuntu.  I have these settings:

**echo $TERM displays xterm-color256**

**echo $SHELL displays /bin/sh**

Specifically, I'd like:

- The cursor-up key to perform the "history-search-backward" function
- The cursor-down key to perform the "history-search-forward" function
- The cursor-left and cursor-right keys to move thru the command just retrieved
- To be able to change the command by moving the cursor and typing over the retrieved command

I've been able to use **stty erase ^?** in /etc/profile to set the backspace key, but my attempts at using **~/.inputrc** to control the cursor keys have been unsuccessful. Trying different terminal types (eg **export TERM=xterm**  or **export TERM=vt100**) has also not helped.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like the USS shell has some ksh features. You probably won't get full readline-like customizability, but try `set -o emacs` and see if that gives you at least some use of the cursor keys

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MarkPlotnick, but that causes cursor up to type an "A", down to type a "B", Alt-Cursor-Up now types a "1;3A" Alt-Cursor-Down a "1;3A".  Ctrl-Cursor-Up is "1;5A", Ctrl-Cursor-Down is "1; 5B".

Comment: OK, looks like the `set -o emacs` had no effect on interpreting cursor keys.